# OpenCV c++ error - assertion failed

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to find the color of a selected pixel. 
I got this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x770FC42D in OpenCV_Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x003atEEB84.
```

in the console it wrote assertion error.

I used this code:

```
static void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int, void* imgptr){
    if (event != 1)
        return;
    else{
            Mat& imgMat = (*(Mat*)imgptr);
            Vec3f intensity = imgMat.at<Vec3f>(Point(x,y));
            uchar blue = intensity.val[0];
            uchar green = intensity.val[1];
            uchar red = intensity.val[2];

            imshow("Display window", imgMat);
            waitKey(1);
    }
}

int main(){

    Mat img = imread("colorImg2.jpg");

    if (!img.data)
    {
        std::cout << " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("Display window", 0);
    setMouseCallback("Display window", onMouse, &img);

    imshow("Display window", img);
    waitKey(0);

}
```

I saw that it happens in this line `Vec3f intensity = imgMat.at<Vec3f>(x, y);`
I tried the float example and the uchar (used in the code) and i got the same error.

Comment: Is there a reason you are waiting for a key press in the `onMouse` event handler? And only wait for a single millisecond?

Comment: That was the problem :) thanks!!!
Forgot to delete it after changing the code...

Comment: it should be Vec3b. Vec3f will even lead to a buffer overflow